# Preserve underscore in FileName - Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, underscore.js, preserve

I am trying to rename the downloaded files from ssrs in firefox. The default name is the actual filename.pdf or some other available options.I have made some changes to ReportServer.js file to fix the default name of the downloaded files. It is working in IE and chrome..I have changed the default file name by adding "_YYYYMMDD" at the end of the file name so let's say it appears as Filename_YYYYMMDD.pdf.
The solution is working in Chrome and IE's latest version. With firefox, it is however replacing "_" with "%5F" so the name appears as Filename%5FYYYYMMDD.pdf

Is there any way i can fix it in firefox? Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: you can use decodeURIComponent() function for your file name.

Comment: Thank you  Pareek. It doesnt seem to work. While downloading, it seems like FF encodes the underscore. Any other way? I am doing something like this: r.ExportUrlBase = url.substring(0,i) + "FileName= +oldFileName+postfixFileName + url.substring(j);

Answer (score 1):

You pass the string to `decodeURIComponent()` and assign the result to the variable referencing the file name

```
fileName = decodeURIComponent(fileName)
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. This is my where i am setting the filenamer.ExportUrlBase = url.substring(0,i) + "FileName="+oldFileName+postfixFileName+url.substring(j);   I cant seem to embed decodeURIComponent method in it. If i do this with the filename only, it doesnt work.